# LaTeX \includegraphics and textline

Tags: graphics, latex

Ok, I am beat. I tried a few things but I am unable to make this happen. I need some help now.
I want to be able to have some text and picture side by side (only one line, thus no need for wrapping or other fun. The picture is small enough to fit in a text line):

```
This is a text <temp.jpg placed center to the textline>
```

Problem is, when I use

```
This is a text \includegraphics{temp.jpg}
```

the pictures baseline is alligned with the text baseline. I want the picture (vertical) center to be aligned with the text baseline. How can I make this possible?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
This is a text $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics{temp.jpg}}}$
```

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you want `\raisebox` (see the [raisebox section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#Raisebox) of the LaTeX wikibook), with a negative argument.  Use dimensions ex (the notional height of an 'x' in the current font) or `\baselineskip` (the size between text baselines) as your units.

If you want to do more complicated things, such as move the graphics box down by half its height, you can, but it gets fiddly.  If the graphic size isn't unpredictable, you're probably better off tuning this by hand anyway.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of that. This might work, but Alexey's short solution is compact and less complicated.

Comment: Thanks to [Daniel Hernández](http://stackoverflow.com/users/825325/daniel-hernandez) for spotting the broken link.  @Daniel: sorry your suggested edits seem to have been rejected by editors – I presume that the preferred form is to write a comment pointing out the problem.

Comment: Daniel added a useful [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1834742), which various editors seem to have rejected.  Is there any way I, as the author of the answer, can object to this rejection? (there doesn't appear to be any mechanism on the edit review page).  Instead, I've had to edit Daniel's fix into the answer by hand, which adds work.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, most simple answer `\raisebox{-0.5\totalheight}{<your graphic here>}`

```
This is a text \raisebox{-0.5\totalheight}{\includegraphics{temp.jpg}}
```

**Explanation:**
`\raisebox` moves vertically the whole text/picture given as second argument. The first argument is the vertical shift as a length. This command provides the length `\totalheight` which is, self-explanatory, the height of the whole text/picture that you want to raise. The factor `-0.5` lowers exactly at the half of the length(as the question demands). For aesthetic adjustments just modify the factor's value.

By the way, with this method there is no need to get into math mode as in @AlexeiMalistov answer, and no need of double command `\vcenter` + `\hbox`